# Sorting Columns Based on Values from different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a table with Names, Type of Sale, Location and Amount. The names is taken from a different sheet with formula ={"";Unique(rawData!A:A)} and for other columns like location Amount and type of sales, I've used Vlookup and Sumifs function based on the requirement.

This is working fine, but, when I try to sort with the googlescript with the code

```
function autoSort() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Summary")
  const range = ws.getRange("A2:D1000")

  range.sort({column:4, ascending: false})
}
```

the Amount column is getting sorted but again it is changing back in a blink.

Is this due to the formula ={"";Unique(rawData!A:A)} or I'm doing something else wrong here.. Kindly help

Comment: `Is this due to the formula ={"";Unique(rawData!A:A)}` most probably that's the case. Can you provide a copy of your spreadsheet, free of sensitive information?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the spreadsheet.. as the data involved is fully from my organization.. :(

Comment: In that case, is there a reason for keeping both a script and a formula for handling the same cells? This often leads to problems, as in your current case. I'd suggest you pick one.

Answer (score 0):

### What's going wrong?

When you are "manually" sorting your data with the script, your `={"";Unique(rawData!A:A)}` formula does not change. All you are doing is rearranging the other vlookup and sumif physical formulas around the sheet. Since the names never change, neither are your resulting values.

###### This is a very basic and rudimentary explanation. I'm sure there is a much better explanation for what is happening, but my basic understanding is just that you can't sort formulas because ultimately nothing about the order actually changes

---

### A solution?

Do do everything in one formula in order to group everything together.

I have come up with one to do this.

```
=ifna(
   sort(
      {
       Unique(rawData!A2:A),
       arrayformula(VLOOKUP(Unique(rawData!A2:A), rawData!A2:D10, 2, 0)),
       arrayformula(VLOOKUP(Unique(rawData!A2:A), rawData!A2:D10, 3, 0)),
       arrayformula(VLOOKUP(Unique(rawData!A2:A), rawData!A2:D10, 4, 0))
      },
      4, 0
   )
)
```

This pulls all the data at once (including the names) and sorts it as a whole. The `VLOOKUP` references the unique array, instead of an actual cell reference. This allows the values to be sorted, without rearranging the physical formulas. Below is a link to the spreadsheet I created to test this. This may need to be changed and edited to your liking (especially given that I didn't incorporate any `SUMIF` formulas), but it does what you appear to be asking for.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yj0IhZsbbXvhHQfkhn3P8Ac-A8nq5D3fiOZAsVYiPVs/edit?usp=sharing

This formula creates a blank first row. This can be fixed by filtering out blank values in the unique formula, but I left it as it was right now to avoid confusion. If you would like help incorporating that, just let me know and I can edit the formula.